# Loop a method call based on user choice

Tags: c#

Based on the user choice can we call the method infinitely. If a User presses the Key "Y", call the method, else quit the console app.

Below is the code:

```
namespace IR_CSharp
{
    class Program
    {
        private void GetASCIIValue()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to get the ascii value: ");
            int value = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("ASCII value is {0}", value);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program prog = new Program();
            string choice = "0";
            prog.GetASCIIValue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: _"Can we call the method infinitely?_" - Yes, you can.

Comment: Have you heard of a while loop?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/while

Answer (score 0):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ConsoleKeyInfo keyinfo;
        do
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter a value to get the ascii value: ");
            int value = Console.Read();
            Console.WriteLine("ASCII value is {0}", value);

            keyinfo = Console.ReadKey();

        }
        while (keyinfo.Key != ConsoleKey.Y);
    }
}
```